# what's the relationship of Spacy and NLPre?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I used the NLPre package to identify the Keywords. But I seldom use Spacy. I want to know the relationship between NLPre and Spacy.
I have seen the website:https://spacy.io/universe/project/NLPre. But I still don't know the relationship.

Looking forward to your answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the spaCy Universe (and also confirmed by looking through the source a bit), NLPre is written on top of spaCy. That is, it's a tool built using spaCy.

Answer (score 0):

spaCy is a free, open-source library for NLP in Python. It's written in Python and is designed to build information extraction or natural language understanding systems. It's built for production use and provides a concise and user-friendly API